# Using Output from Python Code on Android

Tags: android, python, midi

I found a nice library ([mido](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mido)) in Python and would like to use it directly in Android.

I found a way to link Python and Java ([py4j](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j)). But I don't understand how can I use it on Android.

My expected workflow is as follows. I invoke the Python library (by supplying a MIDI file to it) from Android -> Python library processes the input and returns the output to Android code.

If that is not possible, can anyone suggest a good MIDI parsing library for Android that handles SysEx (System Exclusive) events well? I am using [MidiDroid](https://github.com/pdrogfer/MidiDroid) but it doesn't always work well with SysEx events.

I would really prefer running mido on Android because the SysEx events are created and stored in a MIDI file using mido on Python, which I then parse on Android.